# How to open RStudio GUI which are in an Ubuntu Server from MacOS?

Tags: r, macos, ubuntu, ssh, rstudio

Currently I have installed RStudio in Ubuntu server. When I use another linux and windows system to ssh it, I can see the RStudio GUI. However, when I start to use my Macbook to ssh, nothing appears.

the command I entered is 
"rstudio"

No error messages appear and no RStudio GUI appears either.

This is really confusing, can anyone give me some suggestions or ideas on what to do?

Comment: Problem of port forwarding? Authorization in firewall? You don't provide any command and description of port used.

Comment: RStudio on a remote machine is accessed through the web (generally at port 8787, so http://ip-of-your-machine:8787). Typically, if you're using `ssh` you would not expect to see a GUI, just command line R. Running `rstudio` on remote machine will not push the GUI to your machine only access whatever RStudio pushes to ssh (which i belive is nothing).

Comment: The same configuration Mac+Ubuntu works fine for me.  
From Mac: ***ssh -X user@ubuntu***. Then ***rstudio&***